# Balls and bins: filling $N$ bins with at least $K$ balls

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, balls-in-bins, coupon-collector

Suppose an infinite number of balls are thrown into $N$ bins
(uniformly distributed).

What is the expectancy of the number of balls needed in order to fill all bins with at least $K$ balls in each bin.

---

I found answers to this problem with $K=1$ and even a partial answer to $K=2$
but nothing for the generalized form.

Comment: Can you provide us with your solution for K = 1 and K = 2?

Comment: This is the coupon collector's problem except that you need $K$ of each instead of $1$ of each.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer in the following paper:

https://faculty.wharton.upenn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Double-dixie-cup-problem.pdf

the expectancy of collecting $m$ balls each bins (having $n$ bins) is:

$$n(\log(n) + (m-1)\log\log n + o(1) )$$

*** this analysis is done for $m$-fixed and $n$-large